# How to do multiple lines with a customizable gaps in a fragment shader

Tags: math, shader, trigonometry, fragment-shader

I'm looking to draw a pattern with several lines separated by customizable spaces. The gap between lines can be independently controlled from the line thickness. The challenge ! I'd like to avoid using a loop, which could handle this problem easily.

With a function like `cos()`, for instance, the space between lines is always proportional to the size of the lines, as shown in the image below:

[image]

However, I tried to have a function that behaves more like the example below:

[image]

But I'm facing some difficulties in achieving this (my level in math). Do you have any suggestions to help me ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your image, it seems part of the sin() function between horizontal lines. 
You have some user values:

- The starting distance until the sin() starts, `x0`
- The distance in the sin() part `ds`
- The distance in the horizontal part  `dh`
- The vertical distance for all parts relative to origin `vd`

The target is a function f(x) that returns the value in the proper part.

A simple function may tell where a  `x` lies on:

```
int f(float x, inout float pos) //returns 0: at initial part,  1: at sin() part,   2: at horizontal
{
   if (x <= x0)
   {
      pos = 0;
      return 0;
   }
 
   pos = x0;  // 'pos' is the 'x' of the beginning of this part
   while (1)
   {
       if (x <= pos + ds)
          return 1;   //sin() part
       pos += ds;
       if (x <= pos + ds + dh)
          return 2;
       pos += dh;
   }
}
```

I'm sure there is a better, faster, function. I let it to you to find it out.

Once you have the range just calculate the `y` value.

```
float y(float x, int type_of_part, float pos)
{
   if (type_of_part==0 || type_of_part==2)
      return vd;

   //sin() needs the horizontal part = PI
   float dr = x - pos; //'x' relative to beginning of sin()
   return vd + sin(dr / ds * PI);
}
```

I hope you get the idea. I let to you to join both functions and to correct my GLSL typos.